# How to find the sum of this cos series

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry

$$S = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(\theta\log(k))}{k^a}$$

How do I go about finding the value of S, given that $\theta \to \infty$ and $0 < a < 1$.

> Any special techniques that might be
>   helpful in calculating this sum?

EDIT: 
Just to give some background,

I was actually trying to figure out
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(\theta\log(k))}{k^a} - \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\cos(\theta\log(k + 0.5))}{(k+0.5)^a}$$

Since that expression was a bit complicated, I decided to write the common version...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your value is basically the value of the Riemann zeta function:
$$
S = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{Re (e^{i \theta \log(k)})}{k^a} = Re( \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} k^{i \theta - a} ) = Re( \zeta ( a - i \theta ))
$$
You want to evaluate this on the critical strip $0 < a < 1$.

The good news is that there is an enormous amount of literatue on the Riemann zeta. The bad news is that this function is nasty on the critical strip.

Comment: More bad(?) news: The sum defining the zeta function is only convergent for $a>1$. To get into the critical strip one needs to use analytic continuation.

Comment: Spot on!!! +1. Yea, I was playing around with properties of the zeta function... More precisely the Dirichlet eta function... I got stuck while evaluating this... Maybe I should edit this question and give some details on what I was doing...

Comment: @rpg16: I presume you've seen the [Riemann-Siegel formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Riemann-SiegelFormula.html), which I believe was what Michael and Hans were alluding to?

Comment: Thanks, I'll check out that link J.M.